# framer.motion not works slideshow image changes but works on first load of page

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I want to create slideshow(carousel) with react(nextjs),tailwind,framer.motion.This is the code:

```
"use client";

import "./Carousel.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Carousel = () => {
  const carousel_images = ["/static/1_400-200.jpg", "/static/2_400-200.jpeg"];
  const [slideNumber, setSlideNumber] = useState(0);
  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (slideNumber > carousel_images.length - 2) {
      setSlideNumber(0);
      return;
    }
    setSlideNumber(slideNumber + 1);
  };
  const prevSlide = () => {
    if (slideNumber == 0) {
      setSlideNumber(carousel_images.length - 1);
      return;
    }
    setSlideNumber(slideNumber - 1);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // const interval = setInterval(() => {
    //   nextSlide();
    // }, 3000);
    // return () => {
    //   clearInterval(interval);
    // };
  }, [slideNumber]);

  return (
    <div id="Carousel" className=" mt-10 mx-auto w-[320px] ">
      <div id="slide" className={`w-full relative h-28`}>
        <div
          className="fa-solid fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-gray-300 absolute top-1/2 left-2 cursor-pointer z-10
        text-center align-middle rounded-full"
          onClick={prevSlide}
        ></div>{" "}
        <div
          className="fa-solid fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-gray-300 absolute top-1/2 right-2 cursor-pointer z-10
      text-center align-middle rounded-full"
          onClick={nextSlide}
        ></div>
        {carousel_images.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <motion.img
              initial={{ x: 320, opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
              transition={{
                delay: 1,
                x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 100 },
                default: { duration: 2 },
              }}
              src={carousel_images[slideNumber]}
              key={index}
              className={`absolute top-0 left-0 h-28 w-[320px]`}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Carousel;
```

animation works just on page reloading once time. On nextSlide and prevSlide click image changes but no animation.

I expect to run animation on every image change but not working.